# `Unit` Return Type of Closure

Tags: scala, closures

Given the following closure:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int) { 
     |   def bar(y: Int) = x + y
     |   bar(55)
     | }
foo: (x: Int)Unit
```

Why is its return type `Unit`? I would've expected an `Int`.

```
scala> foo(55)
scala>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the procedure syntax. i.e. you don't have an `=` after the method declaration, so the method will return `Unit`. What you want is:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int) = { 
     |     def bar(y: Int) = x + y
     |     bar(55)
     | }
foo: (x: Int)Int
```

The value of `bar(55)` in your example is being discarded, which you can catch via compiler flag:

```
$ scala -Ywarn-value-discard

scala> def foo(x: Int) { 
     |     def bar(y: Int) = x + y
     |     bar(55)
     | }
<console>:9: warning: discarded non-Unit value
           bar(55)
              ^
foo: (x: Int)Unit
```

Comment: Interesting related discussions: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/q1YX7NC1geM
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605